# Is $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ a Real Vector Space?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

According to Axler’s “Linear Algebra Done Right”, a Real Vector Space is a Vector Space over $\mathbb{R}$.

So, does this mean that $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is a Real Vector Space?

Comment: I doubt that you're quoting it correctly: "a Vector Space over $\mathbb C^n$" makes no sense because $\mathbb C^n$ is not a field.  It is true that $\mathbb C^n$ is a real vector space, i.e. a vector space over $\mathbb R$.  To see that, check that it satisfies the definition.

Comment: Sorry. I completely butchered what I wrote earlier. What I mean to say was "a Real Vector Space is a Vector Space over $\mathbb{R}$". I've edited it already.

Thanks for the answer too btw.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb C^n$ can be seen as a real vector space.

Comment: In general, for any fields $F\leq K$, $K^n$ with its usual addition, and the scalar multiplication being the usual one with scalars restricted to $F$, is an $F$-vector space. Note, however, that $\mathbb{C}^n$ is not an $n$-dimensional real vector space, though. It's real dimension is $2n$.

Comment: According to Axler's definition, you should say either "over $\mathbb R$" or "real vector space", but not both.

Comment: It depends on how you define scalar multiplication.